# Rails - Entered Data Not Displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is most likely a newbie question...
I'm currently working on my first rails project and have a couple issues to solve.

Here is the [video](https://share.getcloudapp.com/p9uKn4eZ) as well as the [Github link](https://github.com/planetlucid/Ruby_On_Rails_Project).

How do I display the entry once it’s entered on the page?
How do I get the list of entries to show up?

Currently it’s throwing the following error, but I’ve checked my spelling/pluralizations and don't see an issue.

```
undefined local variable or method `comicbook' for #<#<Class:0x00007fb1d23d3728>:0x00007fb1d23d18b0>
Did you mean?  comicbooks
---
        <th>Squad</th>
    </tr>
    <% render partial: 'comicbooks/comicbook', locals: {comicbook: comicbook }%>
</table>
```

comicbooks_controller.rb

```
class ComicbooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comicbooks = Comicbook.all
  end

  def create
    @comicbook = Comicbook.new(comicbook_params)
    if @comicbook.save
      redirect_to comicbooks_url
    else
      @errors = @comicbook.errors.full_messages
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @comicbook = Comicbook.new
    @comicbook.person = Person.new
    @comicbook.squad = Squad.new
  end

  def edit
    unless @comicbook = Comicbook.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @error = ['Comicbook Not Found']
      redirect_to comicbooks_url
    end
  end

  def update
  end

  def comicbook_params
    params.require(:comicbook).permit(:title, :person_attributes => [:name], :squad_attributes => [:name])
  end
end
```

Comment: post your controller code, and your views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no variable created in your `_all_comicbooks.html.erb` view which is my assumption for this error.  You need to loop through the data to get this like in the index file.  So, in your index file, you have this line

```
<% @comicbooks.each do |comicbook| %>
   <% render partial: 'comicbook', locals: {comicbook: comicbook }%>
<% end %>
```

So there is a variable `@comicbooks` which is being looped through, and the individual variables for each item are being set to `|comicbook|`.  See how that works?

Without creating the loop and setting what the variable is you are just calling a variable that doesn't exist.

After looking it looks like you are sending a variable to the partial called `comicbooks` which is all the persons, or squads, comicbooks, so loop through that and create the `comicbook` variable.

So my guess is you want this in the `_all_comicbooks.html.erb` view

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Comicbook</th>
    <th>Hero</th>
    <th>Squad</th>
  </tr>
  <% comicbooks.each do |comicbook| %>
    <%= render partial: 'comicbooks/comicbook', locals: {comicbook: comicbook }%>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you Rockwell. the page now loads! my next step is to get the entries to show up. i see them in my console.

Comment: Well if this solved it mark it as the answer and ask that question in another post.  Does it make sense what you had to do and why?

Comment: Oh, I think you just have to output it be adding the equal sign `<%= render...`  I updated my answer